# How to parse json using jarray?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
[
  {
    "religion": "Hindu",
    "otherreligionidtype": "1",
    "caste": "SC",
    "personwithdhhhy": "No",
    "purpogfgggan": "Studies",
    "typeongghance": "dontknow",
    "proposehhhgenure": "dontknow",
    "repajjgjequency": "Monthly",
    "sajgjgank": "yes",
    "savijgjcno": "975568592379236",
    "mjjggde": "7397576",
    "ifggde": "658545",
    "spouseinfo": [
      {
        "spousename": "Roshni",
        "spousekycidtype": "PAN Card",
        "spousekycidno": "56753",
        "spousedob": "26/05/1989"
      }
    ],
    "nominejeinfo": [
      {
        "nomijjjjgjme": "Krrish",
        "nomineekjgype": "Aadhar Card",
        "nomineekjgdno": "87494726"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How to parse this  json using jarray

Comment: You need to show a minimal effort before posting a question. SO isn't a code generator.

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom Class

```
public class Spouseinfo
{
    public string spousename { get; set; }
    public string spousekycidtype { get; set; }
    public string spousekycidno { get; set; }
    public string spousedob { get; set; }
}

public class Nominejeinfo
{
    public string nomijjjjgjme { get; set; }
    public string nomineekjgype { get; set; }
    public string nomineekjgdno { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string religion { get; set; }
    public string otherreligionidtype { get; set; }
    public string caste { get; set; }
    public string personwithdhhhy { get; set; }
    public string purpogfgggan { get; set; }
    public string typeongghance { get; set; }
    public string proposehhhgenure { get; set; }
    public string repajjgjequency { get; set; }
    public string sajgjgank { get; set; }
    public string savijgjcno { get; set; }
    public string mjjggde { get; set; }
    public string ifggde { get; set; }
    public List<Spouseinfo> spouseinfo { get; set; }
    public List<Nominejeinfo> nominejeinfo { get; set; }
}
```

I usually add newtonsoft Package

```
var deserializedlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourjsonString);
```

**Edit**
For reading spousename

```
for(int i=0;i<deserializedlist.spouseinfo.Count();i++)
{
 string tempspousename=deserializedlist.spouseinfo[i].spousename;
}
```

Comment: i have created the class file but i want to read values from spouseinfo and the field is spouse name after the json is created

Comment: Did you add the newtonsoft package and deserialize? now you can see edit

Comment: i want to parse this using jarray.This is the code which i have written

Comment: JArray jobj = JArray.Parse(detailentry1);
       
        foreach (var detail1 in jobj)
        {
            txt_pltenure.Text = detail1["proposedloantenure"].ToString();
            rbtn_religion.SelectedValue = detail1["religion"].ToString();
           
           
        }

Comment: Can you add your custom class and your JArray  code as edit in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you insist on using JArray for some reason this code should the trick

```
   var json = JArray.Parse(s);
        foreach (JObject obj in json.Children<JObject>())
        {
            foreach (JProperty property in obj.Properties())
            {

                if (property.Value as JArray!=null)
                {
                    var jsonArray = JArray.Parse(property.Value.ToString());
                     Console.WriteLine(property.Name + ":");
                    foreach(JObject o in jsonArray.Children<JObject>())
                        foreach(JProperty p in o.Properties())
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " " + p.Value.ToString());
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    string name = property.Name;
                    string value = property.Value.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(name + " " + value);
                }
            }
        }
```